# Solving: $2z + \overline{z} + 4 = \frac{z}{1-i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following complex equation:
$2z + \overline{z} + 4 = \frac{z}{1-i}$

I have tried doing it by assuming $z = x + yi$

but at a point I get, $2x-3xi+y-4i+4 = 0$ which is just unsolvable

Any other method or any kind of help would be great!!

Comment: Why is $2x+y-i(3x+4)=0$ unsolvable?

Comment: @healynr sorry my bad, the eq is: 2−3+−4 + 4 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different way to solve this linear equation with conjugate, without using real and imaginary parts:

First collect the terms in $z$ getting

$\frac{3-i}2z+\overline z=-4$

Apply the conjugate equation:

$z+\frac{3+i}2\overline z=-4$

Take $3+i$ times the first equation minus twice the second eliminating the conjugate:

$3z=-4-4i$

(*Was I lucky to get a real coefficient for $z$ after eliminating $\overline z$ in this way? Not really. The derived coefficient on $z$ will **always** be real. But it could be zero, in which case there is either no solution or a nonunique solution.*)

And do an ordinary complex division:

$z=\frac{-4-4i}3$

I check:

$\frac{-8-8i}3+\frac{-4+4i}3+4=\frac{-4-4i}{3-3i}$

$\frac{0-4i}3=(-\frac43)(\frac{1+i}{1-i})$

$-\frac43i=-\frac43i☆$

Answer (score 5):

When you get equation like
$$ 2x-3xi + y- 4i +4 = 0$$
an you know that $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, it means that the real and imaginary parts are equal to $0$ separately:
$$ 2x+y+4 = 0 $$
$$ -3x - 4 = 0$$

Comment: sorry bud, I realised just now that I mistyped there is also a +4 in the end, so the eq would be: 2−3+−4 + 4=0, also I think assuming z = x + yi is not the appropriate way in the first place

Comment: I think if somehow we can solve for z. that would solve the equation

Answer (score 0):

The equation could also be manipulated in this way, using the identity $ \ z + \overline{z} \ = \ 2·\mathfrak{Re}(z) \ \ : $

$$ \ 2z \ + \ \overline{z} \ + \ \overline{z} \ + \ 4 \ \ = \ \ \frac{z·(1 + i)}{2} \ + \ \overline{z} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 8·(\mathfrak{Re}(z) + 1) \ \ = \ \ z·(1 + i) \ + \ 2·\overline{z} \ \ . $$

The left side of the equation is now a real number $ \ ( \ 8x + 8 \ $ in your notation), so the imaginary part of the right side is zero.  We then find

$$ 8x \ + \ 8 \ \ = \ \ ( \ x \ + \ yi \ + \ xi \ - \ y \ ) \ + \ ( \ 2x \ - \ 2yi \ ) 
 $$
$$ xi \ - \ yi \ \ = \ \ 0·i \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ \ \ , \ \ \ 8x \ +  \ 8 \ \ = \ \ 3x \ - \ y \ \ = \ \ 2x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ = \  -\frac43 \ \  . $$
So $ \ z \ = \ -\frac43·(1 + i) \ \ . $